# Error al recorrer Array asociativo PHP

Tags: php, array, pdo

Buenas tardes, tengo la siguiente duda, ¿Por qué no se despliega en pantalla el valor que contiene la columna a la que quiero acceder?

Tengo este código PHP con el que verifico el Login de un usuario.

```html
public function verificarUsuario($nombre_usuario,$password_usuario){
  $modelo = new Conexion();
  $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
  $sql = "select nickname, password
    from usuarios
    where nickname = :nombre_usuario 
    and password = :password_usuario";
  $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);    
  $statement->bindParam(':nombre_usuario', $nombre_usuario);
  $statement->bindParam(':password_usuario', $password_usuario);
  if(!$statement){
   return "Error verifique parametros";
  }else{
   $statement->execute();
   if($statement->rowCount() > 0){ 
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }else{
    return "no hay usuarios con registrados con esos datos";
   } 
  }  
}
```

Que según el manual de PHP (PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) me devuelve un Array asociativo.

> PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: devuelve un array indexado por los nombres de las columnas del conjunto de resultados.

Ahora acá hago la llamada al archivo que contiene el método, y lo ejecuto.

```html
<?php

 require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
 require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');
 session_start();

 $usuario = $_POST['var1'];
 $pass = $_POST['var2'];

 if(strlen($usuario) > 0 && strlen($pass) > 0){
  $consultas = new Consultas();
  $mensaje = $consultas->verificarUsuario($usuario, $pass);
  print_r($mensaje);  
  for($i=0;$i<count($mensaje);$i++) {
   echo $mensaje['nickname'].'<br />';
  }
 }else{
  echo "Por favor rellena ambos campos";
 }  
?>
```

con `print_r($mensaje);` obtengo en la variable mensaje lo siguiente:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [nickname] => usuario1 [password] => usuario12345 ) )

Pero luego cuando intento recorrerlo con el ciclo `for`, me despliega el siguiente mensaje.

> Notice: Undefined index: nickname in C:\xampp\htdocs\TokioGhoul\Controlador\login.php on line 15

Obviamente la linea 15 es donde intento hacer el echo de la columna a la que quiero acceder.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($mensaje);$i++) {
        echo $mensaje['nickname'].'<br />'; <- Aqui se da el error
    }
```

Todo esto lo hago con el fin querer mantener la sesión de un usuario que ingrese.

Por su atención, gracias.

Comment: Te falta acceder al elemento actual del arreglo con el ciclo for, intenta con: $mensaje[$i]['nickname']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si recorres el array con índice numérico debes referir la posición:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($mensaje);$i++) {
    echo $mensaje[$i]['nickname'].'<br />'; 
}
```

Otro modo es recorrerlo con un foreach, que no requiere referir la posición, ya que se ejecuta mientras queden elementos:

```
foreach ($mensaje as $resultado) {
    echo $resultado['nickname'].'<br />'; 
}
```

Comment: Gracias. De nuevo haha. :)

Comment: +1 al foreach :)